# problem new with ubuntu and i cannot install

Tags: kernel, root

I have neu cd ubuntu 12.04. With installation was everything ok and after restart i have error unable to monut root vfs kernel panic and cannot open root file. I tried to install this again but not helpful
My comp. Toshiba with intel processor and version of ubuntu 46x 12.4

Comment: have you checked your install cd for defects? (hold shift while booting from cd and select check cd integrity)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your CD have defects you should try to install it via usb.

if you have a windows machine you can use this software:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

its easy and you will manage to create a USB to boot it.